# onkeypress event listener not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have requirement to not to use html event handler. So I am trying to handle it from script . I made a small function but it is not working

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function lld () {
    document.getElementById('me').onkeypress= myfunction()
}

function myfunction(){
    alert('hiiiii')
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="me" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why voted down, did I asked something wrong. I just put here a problem which I am facing

Comment: You mean you need to avoid INLINE event handlers

Comment: Yes exactly. But here i am talking about voted down

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. Please uncomment the window.onload line because it's confusing otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('me').onkeypress= myfunction;

function myfunction(){
    alert('hiiiii');
}
```

Comment: why brackets returning value without keypress

Comment: `document.getElementById('me').onkeypress` should be a pointer to a function which will be called when the event is fired. In this case the assignment `onkeypress= myfunction;` is not assigning a value. Instead the function name is pointed to the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DQTTe/)

**JS CODE**

```
function myfunction() {
    alert('hiiiii');
}

document.getElementById('me').onkeypress= myfunction;
```

​

Answer (score 1):

`myfunction()` is the value returned by the function. You need to set `onkeypress` to the function itself, not the returned value :

```
document.getElementById('me').onkeypress= myfunction;
```

The whole code could be :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(){
    alert('hiiiii')
}

window.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById('me').onkeypress= myfunction;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks your answer working great for me, please help me to understand what is the use of these () in function

Comment: `a = myfunction()` sets the value of `a` as the returned value of `myfunction`. While `a = myfunction` sets it to the function itself.